# Ingest pipeline for create/update document dates

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to achieve Mysql like behaviour adding inserted_at/updated_at on metadata for each doc I index through ES pipeline.

My pipeline is like:

```
{
  "description": "Adds createdAt and updatedAt style timestamps",
  "processors": [
    {
      "set": {
        "field": "_source.indexed_at",
        "value": "{{_ingest.timestamp}}",
        "override": false
      }
    },
    {
      "set": {
        "field": "_source.updated_at",
        "value": "{{_ingest.timestamp}}",
        "override": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I have like no mapping only tried it adding one doc:

```
POST test_pipelines/doc/1?pipeline=timestamps
{
  "foo": "bar"
}
```

The pipeline successful creates `indexed_at` and `updated_at`:

```
{
  "_index": "test_pipelines",
  "_type": "doc",
  "_id": "1",
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "indexed_at": "2018-07-12T10:47:27.957Z",
    "updated_at": "2018-07-12T10:47:27.957Z",
    "foo": "bar"
  }
}
```

But if I try to update the doc 1 the field `indexed_at` it's changing every time to the same date the document it's updated.

Update request example:

```
POST test_pipelines/doc/1?pipeline=timestamps
{
  "foo": "bor"
}
```

There's any way to tell processor to not update `indexed_at` field?

Comment: How do you update the document?

Comment: @banuj I've updated the question with the request. Usually I do bulkRequest with a lot of POST calls.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because the `set` processor will only operate within the context of the document you're sending, not the one stored (if any). Hence, `override` has no effect here since the document you send does neither contain `indexed_at` nor `updated_at`, which is the reason why both fields are set on each call.

When you `PUT` your document a second time, you're not updating it, you're actually re-indexing it from scratch (i.e. you're overriding the first version you sent). Ingest pipelines [do not work with update operations](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/17895). For instance, if you try the following update call, it will fail.

```
POST test_pipelines/doc/1/_update?pipeline=timestamps
{
  "doc": {
    "foo": "bor"
  }
}
```

If you want to stick with your ingest pipeline, the only way to make it work is to `GET` the document first and then update the field(s) you want. For instance,

```
# 1. index the document the first time
PUT test_pipelines/doc/1?pipeline=timestamps
{
  "foo": "bar"
}

# 2. GET the indexed document
GET test_pipelines/doc/1

# 3. update the foo field and index it again
PUT test_pipelines/doc/1?pipeline=timestamps
{
  "indexed_at": "2018-07-20T05:08:52.293Z",
  "updated_at": "2018-07-20T05:08:52.293Z",
  "foo": "bor"
}

# 4. When you GET the document the second time, you'll see your pipeline worked
GET test_pipelines/doc/1
```

This will return:

```
{
  "indexed_at": "2018-07-20T05:08:52.293Z",
  "updated_at": "2018-07-20T05:08:53.345Z",
  "foo": "bor"
}
```

I definitely agree this is really troublesome, but the link I gave above enumerates all the reasons why pipelines are not supported on update operations.

Another way to make it work the way you like (without pipelines) would be to use a scripted upsert operation (which works like steps 2 and 3 above, i.e. GETs and PUTs the document in a single atomic operation), and that would also work with your bulk calls. It basically goes like this. First you need to store a script that you will call for both your indexing and update operations:

```
POST _scripts/update-doc
{
  "script": {
    "lang": "painless",
    "source": "ctx._source.foo = params.foo; ctx._source.updated_at = new Date(); if (ctx._source.indexed_at == null) ctx._source.indexed_at = ctx._source.updated_at;"
  }
}
```

Then, you can index your document the first time like this:

```
POST test_pipelines/doc/1/_update
{
  "script": {
    "id": "update-doc",
    "params": {
      "foo": "bar"
    }
  },
  "scripted_upsert": true,
  "upsert": {}
}
```

The indexed document will look like this:

```
{
    "updated_at": "2018-07-20T05:57:40.510Z",
    "indexed_at": "2018-07-20T05:57:40.510Z",
    "foo": "bar"
}
```

And you can use the exact same call when updating the document:

```
POST test_pipelines/doc/1/_update
{
  "script": {
    "id": "update-doc",
    "params": {
      "foo": "bor"             <--- only this changes
    }
  },
  "scripted_upsert": true,
  "upsert": {}
}
```

The updated document will look like this, exactly what you wanted:

```
{
    "updated_at": "2018-07-20T05:58:42.825Z",
    "indexed_at": "2018-07-20T05:57:40.510Z",
    "foo": "bor"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response @Val .

I will try the update-script apporach. 

In other hand I've tried with `update_by_query`, the pipelines are working as I expected, as I understand `update_by_query` is getting all _source and reindexing with it making pipeline deal with date as expected.

Comment: Cool, yes update by query would work, too, though not ideal for updating a single document