# ElasticSearch Ingest Pipeline: create and update timestamp field

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-7

To create a timestamp field on my indices, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66958236/758836) answer, I have created a [Ingest Pipeline](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest.html) to run over specific indices:

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/auto_now_add
{
  "description": "Assigns the current date if not yet present and if the index name is whitelisted",
  "processors": [
    {
      "script": {
        "source": """
          // skip if not whitelisted
          if (![ "my_index_1",
                 "my_index_2"
              ].contains(ctx['_index'])) { return; }
          
          // always update updated_at
          ctx['updated_at'] = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(new Date());
          
        """
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

then I apply to all indices settings as the default pipeline

```
PUT _all/_settings
{
  "index": {
    "default_pipeline": "auto_now_add"
  }
}
```

After that, I start indexing my objects into those indices. When I query an indexed item, I will get that item with the `updated_at` field updated at the time of the indexing like:

```
{
  _index: 'my_index_1',
  _type: '_doc',
  _id: 'r1285044056',
  _version: 11,
  _seq_no: 373,
  _primary_term: 2,
  found: true,
  _source: {
    updated_at: '2021-07-07 04:35:39',
    ...
  }
}
```

I would like now to have a `created_at` field, that only updates the first time, so I have tried to upsert script above in this way:

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/auto_now_add
{
  "description": "Assigns the current date if not yet present and if the index name is whitelisted",
  "processors": [
    {
      "script": {
        "source": """
          // skip if not whitelisted
          if (![ "my_index_1",
                 "my_index_2",
                 "..."
              ].contains(ctx['_index'])) { return; }
          
           // always update updated_at
          ctx['updated_at'] = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(new Date());
          // don't overwrite if present
          if (ctx != null && ctx['created_at'] != null) { return; }
          
          ctx['created_at'] = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(new Date());
        """
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

but this solution does not seem to work: the condition

```
if (ctx != null && ctx['created_at'] != null) { return; }
```

will always fail, thus resulting in a update of the `created_at` at every object update on the index, in the same way of the `updated_at` field, making it useless.
So, how to prevent that, and make sure that that field `created_at` exists after it has been created by the Ingestion Pipeline?

Comment: Maybe you should try to use doc['created_at'] to check whether if it is null or not and not ctx! Can you try that?

Comment: thanks, how to access `doc` in the script? I cannot use directly `if (doc['created_at'] != null) { return; }`also the syntax `ctx._source` it not supported in processors, since the syntax `ctx[my_field]` must be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As described by @Val in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51435984/8160318):

> ... the ingest pipeline processor(s) will only operate [within the context](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/7.13/painless-ingest-processor-context.html#painless-ingest-processor-context) of the document you're sending, not the one stored (if any).

As such, you won't have access to the underlying `_source` nor `doc` because ingest pipelines were designed for the ***ingest*** phase, not the ***update*** phase.

---

You can of course keep your `auto_now_add` pipeline to auto-add `updated_at`, and you can extend it with `created_at` (if not already present in the ingest payload) by checking `ctx.containsKey` — since `ctx` is essentially a java `Map`:

```json
PUT _ingest/pipeline/auto_now_add
{
  "description": "Assigns the current date if not yet present and if the index name is whitelisted",
  "processors": [
    {
      "script": {
        "source": """
          // skip if not whitelisted
          if (![ "my_index_1",
                 "my_index_2",
                 "..."
              ].contains(ctx['_index'])) { return; }
          
          def now = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(new Date());
          
          // guaranteee updated_at
          ctx['updated_at'] = now;
          
          // add created_at only if nonexistent in the payload
          if (!ctx.containsKey('created_at')) {
            ctx['created_at'] = now;
          }  
        """
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**However, this'll work only for the first time you ingest your document!**

Running:

```json
POST my_index_1/_doc/some_id
{ 
  "some": "param"
}
```

will yield:

```json
{
  "some" : "param",
  "updated_at" : "2021-07-08 10:35:13",
  "created_at" : "2021-07-08 10:35:13"
}
```

Now, in order to auto-increment `updated_at` each time you update a document, **you'll need one more script** — this time stored under *`_scripts`*, not *`_ingest/pipeline`*:

```json
PUT _scripts/incement_update_at__plus_new_params
{
  "script": {
    "lang": "painless", 
    "source": """
      // add whatever is in the params
      ctx._source.putAll(params);
      
      // increment updated_at no matter what was in the params
      ctx._source['updated_at'] = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(new Date());
    """
  }
}
```

Then, as you run your `_update` call, do so by mentioning the above-mentioned `script`:

```json
POST my_index_1/_doc/some_id/_update
{
  "script": {
    "id": "incement_update_at__plus_new_params",
    "params": {
      "your": "new params"
    }
  }
}
```

which'll increment `updated_at` without touching `created_at` and add any other params:

```json
{
   "some":"param",
   "updated_at":"2021-07-08 10:49:44",    <--
   "created_at":"2021-07-08 10:39:55",
   "your":"new params"                    <--
}
```

---

Shameless plug: I discuss [pipelines & scripts](https://elasticsearchbook.com/learn-elasticsearch/post-indexing-updates-488d69498920464999ef35e36e3e8095) in great detail in my [Elasticsearch Handbook](https://elasticsearchbook.com/).